# What happens when your message is considered "foul"?

Tags: bloodborne

When you create a message using the [notebook](http://bloodborne.wikia.com/wiki/Notebook), I noticed you can get it rated as either "fine" or "foul".  I know getting a "fine" rating restores health.  What happens though when you get a foul rating? Does it have any negative consequences?

Answer (score 7):

As far as I can tell (so far) there's no negative consequences. I'm assuming it's purely just an indicator. Lot's of foul ratings = avoid the message, etc.

It's great when your message gets up-voted and you're in a boss fight: You get all that lovely health back!

Comment: Oh I didn't know you get you health back! may drop some more helpful notes ;)

Answer (score 3):

Basically some people can lie and hurt other players; example:

I was playing the other day and I came across a deep hole and couldn't see the bottom properly, there was a note in front of the hole with the message "take a step forward". I got closer to look and actually saw the red "spirit" of another player walk and fall in and die when they hit the floor.

I gave that note a foul rating and also set a note before the foul one saying something along the line of "don't believe people"

So in a nutshell, the foul rating just acts as guidance to whether a note is good advice to follow or not, (usually).

Comment: But are there consequences to leaving a note like that which generates a lot of foul votes? That's the question...

Comment: @DannyBeckett No, I don't think so. I think it literally is a case of just letting players know how useful a note is.

Comment: So does the Appraisals #. you see before voting Fine/Foul, only show Fine votes?